# Universal Authentication Module Rails3 Captive Portal Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We're looking to build a captive portal application in RoR3. We already have a functioning freeradius server and are using an application from drupal (http://drupal.org/project/hotspot) but want our own customisation.

One thing that's important is the ability to capture a parameter in the URL and redirect the request to a different page automatically.

For example, our default request is:

examplehotspot.com/hotspot?NASID=ID-1

I'm trying to figure out how it's possible to redirect to another page. For example:

Client A: ID-1 - redirects to a page A

Client B: ID-2 - redirects to a page B

Is there anyone out there who can point us in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a non-resourceful route, eg. :

```
  match "/hotspot" => redirect "/some_controller/%{NASID}"
```

more info on :

- redirect routes **[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)**
- capturing the query string **[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string)**
- how to acces the query params from a controller **[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object)**

Comment: Cool, that looks easy. What about the uam side of things? Any thoughts about that?

Comment: have a look at [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [omniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth)

Comment: Thanks. We already use devise for authentication but need to do more than just login - our radius clients send a shared secret for example and they authenticate against radius for Internet access

Comment: that's a totally different problem, and you should open another question for this, because the way you turn this question one may only concentrate on the "redirection" problem. Interesting problem, though ; did not know exactly what a radius server is, maybe you could develop a bit what you exactly need to implement. You may finally find some information on most used authorization solutions [on this site](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.html)